# Can i make a shortcut on my homescreen to "unmount USB storage"?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, usb

I frequently connect a USB drive to my Sony Xperia M to listen to music. The only trouble is that i have to go through several steps to un-mount the USB when im done. I have to go to Home->Settings->storage->unmount usb.

This would be made easier if it where possible to have a homescreen icon/widget that i could tap on that would automatically unmount the usb.

Is this possible? or do i need to make my own app to do this?

Comment: Use [QuickShortcutMaker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sika524.android.quickshortcut) or [Activity Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.szalkowski.activitylauncher&hl=en) to find the activity `com.android.settings/com.android.settings.Settings$StorageSettingsActivity` and make the shortcut. See if it works.

Comment: You can add "Storage" shortcut with standard Android tools. Long press on screen -> Add -> Widget -> Settings -> Storage.

Comment: @Alex.S Which Android version and device are you using? I did try your method before posting my first comment but Storage option under that Settings widget isn't available in my Android 4.2.1 or even 5.0.2.

Comment: @Firelord I have this option on LG G2 with 4.4.2 but it is not available on another device with 4.4.2 and 5.1. Sorry for confusion.